# How to change the app status when the app is turned off in Swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, linker

I have no problem running my app.

However, if you click the Share button on my app and complete the share, turn off my app and click on the shared image on another app, it will not go to the login screen. Why doesn't it recognize the background status?

```swift
switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {
    case .background:
        LoginScreen()
        break
    case .inactive:
        WebViewScreen()
        break
    case .active:
        WebViewScreen()
        break
    default:
        break
}
return true
```

So if I press the Shared button and go to my app, I can go to the webview screen without fail. But I don't want to go to the webview screen when the app is off.

### EDIT : 2016 year Document

> Table 2-3  App states State
>
> Description
>
> **Not running**
>
> The app has not been launched or was running but was terminated by the
>   system.
>
> **Inactive**
>
> The app is running in the foreground but is currently not receiving
>   events. (It may be executing other code though.) An app usually stays
>   in this state only briefly as it transitions to a different state.
>
> **Active**
>
> The app is running in the foreground and is receiving events. This is
>   the normal mode for foreground apps.
>
> **Background**
>
> The app is in the background and executing code. Most apps enter this
>   state briefly on their way to being suspended. However, an app that
>   requests extra execution time may remain in this state for a period of
>   time. In addition, an app being launched directly into the background
>   enters this state instead of the inactive state. For information about
>   how to execute code while in the background, see Background Execution.
>
> **Suspended**
>
> The app is in the background but is not executing code. The system
>   moves apps to this state automatically and does not notify them before
>   doing so. While suspended, an app remains in memory but does not
>   execute any code.
>
> When a low-memory condition occurs, the system may purge suspended
>   apps without notice to make more space for the foreground app.

The 2016 Apple document had a status value of '`Notruning`'. Is it gone now? Is there a substitute status value?

Comment: Do you have control on the other app? If yes, have you tried using deeplink back to your app instead of running it?

Comment: @manman I don't have control of other apps. Simply turn off my app and run my app again to go to the login screen. But when I go using Deeplink, I go straight to the Web view.

Comment: i think you are not handled for deep linking to Url Scheme from UIApplication Delegates function.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

When app comes over another app like a phone call comes or as in your case via share button. Your app will go in inactive state and not in background. Please put print statement and try to find out in which state your app is in, I suspect it is not in background state.

Comment: How can I change this to background if it's inactive when it comes through another app?